# How to return an array instead of object in JSON response?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've one working REST API developed using Slim PHP framework.

It's working absolutely fine.

The only issue is when there is no error present i.e. an array `$errors` is empty it comes as an array in JSON response but when the array `$errors` contains any error like `$errors['user_name']` then it comes as an object in JSON response.

Actually I want to return the array when error is present. How should I do this? Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: echo json_encode($result); in this pass true like echo json_encode($result,true);

Answer (score 0):

When your `$errors` is not empty, pass it through `json_encode` and echo it.
It will give you JSON object in return, 
then convert JSON object into JavaScript array. (see the following code.)

```
var o = {"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4"}; // your response object here 

var arr = Object.keys(o).map(function(k) { return o[k] });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently got a close issue with Symfony's `JsonResponse::create()`

Turns out arrays with index not **starting at 0** will be encoded into objects, as well as **arrays with "holes"**, and probably any array with at least one **non-int key**.

In other word, arrays with anything else than ***consecutive numeric keys starting from index 0*** seem to be encoded as object.

*I guess this is designed to avoid sending big empty arrays when you map a handful of datas with big indices like [14334, 839493, 246193], and is probably documented somewhere.*

Learning if this is a Symfony of json_encode behavior from comments would be welcomed addition :)

Note : *Even if you return an array, it seems necessary to wrap it in an object for GET request to [prevent some XSSI and JSON-JavaScript Hijacking](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md#always-return-json-with-an-object-on-the-outside).*